# How to deploy Logic App code via Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-logic-apps

I'm currently trying to understand how I can deploy a Logic App from Azure DevOps. I'm trying to give my team the ability to back out changes. Is this possible without using a series of scripts?

I'd like to create a release that does the following

1. Deploy Logic App ARM template
2. Upload code to Logic App from VSTS/DevOps

Comment: what do you mean by code ? there is no code in logic app, but you can deploy your logic app using ARM template, there is no problem, it is only one step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good article on how to prepare the logic apps for CI/CD into multiple environments using ARM template.
You just need to download the ARM template for the Logic app and make changes in the template file, declaring parameters. You will also need to create parameter files for each environment. You can then create a Azure Pipelines and upload the files to the build and release definition.
https://platform.deloitte.com.au/articles/preparing-azure-logic-apps-for-cicd

Answer (score 2):

You should extract the ARM template for your logic app and upload it to DevOps, then make a build and release definition

there are several helpful links available, here is one:

https://platform.deloitte.com.au/articles/preparing-azure-logic-apps-for-cicd

Edit: Link to [Logic App Extractor:](https://github.com/jeffhollan/LogicAppTemplateCreator/tree/master/LogicAppTemplate)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know how to deploy Logic App with VSTS, maybe this [doc](https://medium.com/capgemini-dynamics-365-team/arm-logic-app-deployment-with-vsts-f5be1e582213) could help you.